# preg_replace_callback for cleaning class and ad a generic one

Tags: php, regex

I would like to clean double class attributs in a heading tags and add one if it's not found...

Example :

```
<h1 class="test" class="test"> --> <h1 class="correct test">
<h1 class="test"> --> <h1 class="correct test">
<h1> --> <h1 class="correct">
<h2> --> <h2 class="correct">
```

I tried a lots of things with regex but i'm far from a working solution...

```
$content = preg_replace_callback( '#\<h[1-6]{.}*(class=")\>#i', function( $matches ) {
            var_dump($matches);
        }, $content );
```

I just correct the duplication by moving a ) !!

```
$content = preg_replace_callback( '#(\<h[1-'.$this->options['hx_max_level'].'])(.*?)\>(.*)(<\/h[1-'.$this->options['hx_max_level'].']>)#i', function( $matches ) {
            var_dump($matches);
            if ( ! stripos( $matches[0], 'id=' ) ) :
                    $matches[0] = $matches[1] . $matches[2] . ' style="" id="' . sanitize_title( $matches[3] ) . '">' . $matches[3] . $matches[4];
            endif;
            return $matches[0];
        }, $content );
```

Now i just need to complet my regex to add a class...
Thanks

Comment: show the `regex` solutions you tried.

Comment: What causes the duplication?

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Don't post additional code in comments. Edit your question to include all relative code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally answer my own question :

```
$content = preg_replace_callback( '#(\<h[1-'.$this->options['hx_max_level'].'])(.*?)\>(.*)(<\/h[1-'.$this->options['hx_max_level'].']>)#i', function( $matches ) {
            if ( ! stripos( $matches[0], 'id=' ) ) :
                if(!preg_match('#(class=.)#i',$matches[2])){
                    $matches[2] = $matches[2].' class="ahxm_title"';
                } else {
                    $matches[2] = preg_replace('#(class=.)#i','$1ahxm_title ',$matches[2]);
                }                
                $matches[0] = $matches[1] . $matches[2] . ' id="' . sanitize_title( $matches[3] ) . '">' . $matches[3] . $matches[4];
            endif;
            return $matches[0];
        }, $content );
```

I have corrected the ) which was the cause of the duplication...
And i had an other treatement just for the classes.
Thanks for your help and sorry if my question was not very clear (and my english very fluent)
Bye

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for your problem:

```
$reg = '/(<\w*[^>]*class=[^>]*)class="[^">]*"([^>]*>)/';
$text = '<h1 class="test" foo="bar" class="test" baz="bag"> --> <h1 class="correct test">
<h1 class="test"> --> <h1 class="correct test">
<h1> --> <h1 class="correct">
<h2> --> <h2 class="correct">';


$res = preg_replace_callback($reg, function ($matches) {
    if (count($matches) > 1) {
        return $matches[1].$matches[2];
    }
}, $text);
```

`$res` is that you need!
And for add one if haven't any class...[I'm writing the code]

Comment: it's better than what i did but it's not already doing the job... i'm searching...

Comment: Please specify what you want?

Comment: To be clear, it's for a wordpress plugin... First of all, I need to had a class in every heading tags for the content of an article but i don't want to erase existing classes but add a second one. After an other treatement i do before, the class are in double so i need to clean it too...